# deploy static files with Django modpython

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

I have always wondered how static files are found by server when using Django. Recently I deployed my Django app to a server and I had trouble deploying static files. I always get the error as following :

```
Using the URLconf defined in cms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^gre/
The current URL, static/, didn't match any of these.
```

when I asked for my css file like this `http://gnijuohz.com/static/css/bootstrap.css`

SO 1)

Do I have to do something with my urls.py so that it can find my css files and js files?

Notice that I don't have the root permission on the server,so I can't use the collectstatic command provided by Django.

I did set the STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL in my setting.py so that the STATIC_ROOT point to my static files.

2)

I  am not clear how the whole process works. When I request my css file, does it look through the urls.py to do matches?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116

Comment: @ArgsKwargs Not really. I can't run the command `./manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Who said you have to, it explains both production and development environments...

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I only need production environment.

Answer (score 1):

1.

No, Django should not be serving your static files on a production server. Apache (or whatever server you use) should serve the static files, often found in a directory /static/. That's what `collectstatic` does: it collects all the static files from all your Django apps and it puts them in `STATIC_ROOT` so your server can serve the files.

Locally you can serve the static files by adjusting your `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`.

It's a pity that you can't use `collectstatic` because that's how Django is intended to be used.

2.

As said above, that's not what should happen.

Now, to answer your question, you could create symbolic links in your `STATIC_ROOT` to all the locations where your static files are located. So a symbolic link to each static directory of each Django app.

Comment: That's possible if that works. But you may wish to automate it, so you could write a little script that locally collects the static files before uploading the code to your server. The final result would be the same: as long as the static files can be found by the server, they can be served from that directory.