# django admin static URLs: working for base.css but not for dashboard.css

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '..', 'media/static')
STATIC_URL = '/media/static/
```

In rendered page:

```
<title>Site administration | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css" />
```

The href for base.css is right, but the href for dashboard.css is missing the `media/static/admin`.  Why?

Comment: What is the value of the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting?

Comment: which django version are you using? have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116

Comment: How are you referencing the dashboard css in the template?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.4.  I don't set ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX because it is deprecated in 1.4.  I'm not referencing dashboard.css or base.css myself, only django.contrib.admin is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your template looks like this?

```
<title>Site administration | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/dashboard.css" />
```

Can you access both the files if you try opening them in your browser with the location that they should have? `/media/static/admin/css/base.css` and `/media/static/css/dashboard.css` (or maybe ../admin/...)

Have you added `'django.core.context_processors.static',` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

**UPDATE**

It worked fine for me when I tried the same. In my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />, 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />
```

The rendered HTML (in my current project `/static/` is my STATIC_URL):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />, 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" />
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />, <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />

Comment: @zoo what if you try my approach? Could you access the files?

Comment: Both files are accessible at /media/static/admin/css/.  The question is why django.contrib.staticfiles is producing the right URL for base.css but not for dashboard.css.

Comment: @zoo I'm sure you've made some mistake in your code and it's hard to find without seeing more of it. See my updated answer for my results.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously had some trouble with `STATIC_URL` when I forgot to set the context of `render_to_response`. Without seeing the code you use in your view and template it is quite hard to determine the actual problem, but if it's setting the context and you're using `render_to_response`, try the following:

```
return render_to_response("login.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The same goes for a lot of other render functions. Could you post the view and template?

Comment: If that were the case then no url would be rendered. Btw, I recommend  using [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of render_to_response. Then it would look like `return render(request, 'login.html', {})`

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to cover all the bases, as we know very little about the template and view. It's probably not this, but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Django yells at you that ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated, putting it in your settings.py seems to fix this error some of the time. I haven't had time to source dive, but wherever the 'extra_styles' context, where the dashboard.css comes from, is set still seems to look at the AMP setting.