# Static Files - Page Not Found

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

To see the static files (images and pdf), I defined `STATIC_DIRS` with the values containing directories' names where I upload those files:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/photos/custodia/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/definitiva/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/proforma/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/fpdf/';
)
```

In STATIC_URL:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In Installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ....

    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

)
```

The permissions are 0777.

Now When I want to see the image or pdf files, I get this error message.
Page not found

I am using this URL:
http://127.0.1:8000/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/photos/custodia/powered_by.png

Any Ideas? Why is this problem occuring?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116

Comment: `app-folder/static/` - good.  `project-folder/static/` - bad.  For future viewers, this was my mistake that lead to 404 errors.  `/static/` should be [a sibling of models.py](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15435556/673991).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, static and media files are not served with Django's builtin dev server. If you want it to serve those files directly, add `staticfiles_urlpatterns` and a `MEDIA_URL` pattern to your urlconf.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will only work if `DEBUG` is `True`.

For more information, refer to the [corresponding docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-development).

**Note: You should not do this in production! Always use a separate webserver for static files in production mode.**

Comment: Thanks, i have edit urls.py, so I have insert: from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT), reload the page, and "Page Not Found". -> 'alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/media/photos/custodia/shop-ad.jpg' could not be found     Where are the error?

Comment: @AlexanderT why did you replace MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT with STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: Because the image and pdf files are a Static files? or not?

Comment: @AlexanderT oh, i got something mixed up. in django there's a difference between static files and media files. static files (in STATIC_ROOT) are readonly and they're generated only once when running collectstatic. media files (in MEDIA_ROOT) are usually not read only, i.e. they consist of uploads, dynamically generated files and other stuff.

Comment: @AlexanderT in your case, you created a folder called "media" and added it to the static files dirs variable, that confused me at first. in that case, you don't even need the second urlpatterns row containing the `static()` call, as `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` should already serve all static files for you. re-check your settings.py, verify that STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT are different folders and check the STATIC_URL configuration.

Comment: In Settings.py: MEDIA_ROOT is empty, STATIC_ROOT is empty, STATIC_URL ='/static/', STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/photos/custodia/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/definitiva/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/proforma/',
    '/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/fpdf/',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
)

Comment: Like you tell me, I rename folder media in static. Correctly. Folder media and upload static files..confuses. I'm sorry Danilo

Comment: But a question: I work in local, then in STATIC_URL i put http://127.0.0.1:8000, true? and in STATIC_ROOT i put ( #'/home/alessandro/Scrivania/progetto/static/photos/custodia/',
    .... ) ?   Or i have a confuse static_url in static_root?

Comment: and in settings.py i have insert : from settings import STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT  and   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 but page not foundrest here. I read a command 'python manage.py collectstatic   I must do that command for collect static files at the destination location in my settings?

Comment: @AlexanderT `STATIC_URL` would be `/static/` and `STATIC_ROOT` is a single string to the place you would like your static files to be collected when running `./manage.py collectstatic`. Read the Django docs about staticfiles for more help.