# How to get the link of the file in a FileField?

Tags: django, filefield

how can I get the link of a `FileField`? I tried the `url` field, but it gives the file path:

```
In [7]: myobject.myfilefield.path
Out[7]: u'/home/xxxx/media/files/reference/1342188147.zip'

In [8]: myobject.myfilefield.url
Out[8]: u'/home/xxxx/media/files/reference/1342188147.zip'
```

I was expecting to get `http://<mydomain>/media/files/reference/1342188147.zip`

How can I get that? Do I have to build the string manually?

EDIT

My MEDIA_URL was not set, but I still can't get it to work:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/xxx/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://xxx.com/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class Archive(models.Model):

    #...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
```

**in shell**

```
a = Archive()
a.file = "/some/path/to/file.txt"
a.save()
```

Then I get for `a.path`:

```
"/some/path/to/file.txt"
```

and for `a.url`:

```
"http://xxx.com/media/some/path/to/file.txt"
```

When done programmatically, `a.file = "/some/path/to/file.txt"`, the file is not uploaded to `MEDIA_ROOT`. How can I upload a file in the directory defined by `upload_to`, i.e. in my case `/home/xxx/media/file.txt`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output is based on your settings file, have a look here for an understanding on serving staticfiles in development and/or production:

[Confusion in Django admin, static and media files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116)

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing you have the field defined as:

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="/home/xxx/media/files/reference")
```

in other words is it possible you have defined an absolute path for the upload_path property of the field ?

Try something like

```
from django.conf import settings
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "files/reference")
```