# Django-Compress with debug=false in settings giving error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-compressor

I am facing a weird problem in django. I am using django-compress app. Till debug is true everything goes all right. When I do debug=False, I face the internal server error problem in case of 404 and page without js and css in case of no 404. Worst part is, on console I am getting following error

> UncompressableFileError: 'css/default.css' isn't accesible via
>   COMPRESS_URL ('/static/') and can't be compressed [16/Jul/2012
>   17:17:05] "GET /static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59

Like this it shows 500 for every GET request which are accessible through /static/

So now reason for not getting js and css is clear. But reason for getting error on 404 page is not clear.

Even I tried it disabling and enabling django-compress, but on enabling even normal pages show 404 error

Please let me know what is causing 500 error for all /static/ things and why 404 page gives internal server error.

Comment: How are you serving files? Are your deployment settings right? Did you collect static files and point your server to the root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `DEBUG = True` Django serves the static files. This means it can find the static files in the `/static/` directories of each Django app. In turn, that means django-compressor can find each of the static files it needs to compress.

When `DEBUG = False` Django no longer serves the static files but they should be served by the web server. It does this by serving all static files in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory (often `/static/`). That means all static files from the Django apps need to be put there.

This can be done with the `collectstatic` command (see [The staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) in the Django documentation). After you have run that command all static files should be located in `STATIC_ROOT` and django-compressor should be able to find the files again. That solves the 404 errors you are getting with the static files and when django-compressor works you won't get the 500 errors anymore.

Comment: Exactly like Simeon says. Here's a full example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116

Comment: hey @Simeon I have run collectstatic command then also I am facing same problem. I don't understand what is going wrong. Here what is happening is I think that 404 page s throwing some internal server error and I am getting error, and i don't understand why it can't find static files

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Did you configure your web server to serve the static files? You need to do that and run collectstatic (which you have already done). You can then view the static files.

Comment: @SimeonVisser You are right, but in that case it should give 404 error, why it is giving internal server error

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Perhaps a problem in your web server configuration? If the 500 error is from Apache/nginx then you need to fix that. Or do you see the Django 500 error page?

Answer (score 5):

For Django >= 1.5, if you fall into this problem, make sure you correctly set up your [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) setting. Don't having that setting will make Django Compressor fall into `UncompressableFileError`.

I know we are in 2014 and this question is a bit old ;) but I fall into that problem just today, the solution for my particular case was that and it is not explained nowhere.

Hope it can help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the function of your django's email. Just modify the setting.py like below:

```
DEBUG = False
ADMINS = (
    ('username', 'username@example.com'),
)
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And if happen 500, you will receive a email from your django. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue bothered me as well. Most of solutions are about set up `ALLOWED_HOST`. None of those answers work. I had this issue because of not reading the document carefully.

So, we have to understand this first. It is not realistic that you compiled all assets for each request, right? So, when you deploy your app to production server as well as you turn the debug mode off. You should remember don't let the situation happen.

According to the document, I resolve this issue by putting the code below

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
```

Each time I deploy my app, I run this command

```
python manage.py compress
```

For elastic beanstalk, you can use this command:

```
container_commands:
  ...
  03_compress:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py compress"
```

And this can let you do offline precompiled without compiling all your assets on every single request.

Ref: https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/