# Collectstatic command is uploading static files to root directory

Tags: django, amazon-s3

Where do you set the path to which the command `collectstatic` uploads files?

I thought it was `STATIC_ROOT`. Mine is set as follows in `settings.py`

`STATIC_ROOT = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`

However, it is uploading my files to `http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/` and dumping it in the root rather than the `static` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116

Comment: It's saying that you have to login to the server and then run `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` is used by `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage` to identify a local filesystem path to write the static files to. That isn't what you're trying to do.

Instead, you want the how-to for [Serving static files from a cloud service or CDN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-from-cdn). As that guide suggests, you'll need a storage backend from some project like [django-storages](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/).

Comment: Thanks I am using django-storages. How do I set its upload path to point to my media directory?

Comment: The django-storages documentation for the [S3 backend](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) should answer for everything you need, I think. Depending on your needs you might not want to change `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`, but it documents `STATICFILES_STORAGE` too.

Comment: I don't think `django-storages` supports custom subdirectories. Look at the `django-s3-folder-storage` app