# How To add images in Django project

Tags: python, django

I have problem with adding images in Django project, 
my project is

```
my_app
  manage.py
  my_app 
    urls.py 
    views.py 
    settings.py 
    templates
     home.html
    static
     img
       image1.png
```

in `settings.py`

is all set by default

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In `home.html` I aded code

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static 'img/image1.png' %}" />
```

but it can't load images ,  page not found

```
127.0.0.1:1000/static/img/openicon2.png

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    127.0.0.1:1000/static/img/openicon2.png
```

Can someone help me ? maybe i need to  modify `urls.py` ?

Comment: This has been asked atleast 200 times, please inquire the search at the top right of this page. Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#limiting-use-to-debug-true) which practically holds your answer? possible duplicate of [Confusion in Django admin, static and media files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files) and many others

Comment: I read documentation, and followed steps from   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/ ,  also I check search at the top right this page, nut nothing helps ???

Comment: The documentation you refer to is for _production_ applications, where _the server_ serves static content. You are obviously in local development (DEBUG mode) where Django serves these files. Have a look at the documentation I linked and there's your answer.

Comment: You are requesting `openicon2.png`, and your directory only has `image1.png`, perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: I tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#limiting-use-to-debug-true , and get error 
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:1000/myapp/site_media/image.png

"/path/to/media\image.png" does not exist

Comment: in may ap I added path/to/media/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I've done the following in my settings.py and everythings works ok

```
import os.path,sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\','/')
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, os.pardir))

# other codes and stuff
```

I've added a variable named deveop and I change it depends on if my application runs on development server or apache

```
DEVELOP = True

# other codes and stuff

if DEVELOP == False:
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
if DEVELOP == False:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Comment: Don't create a new setting `DEVELOP` when there is already `DEBUG`. Your `STATICFILES_DIRS` should not include `STATIC_ROOT`.

Answer (score 1):

***Simply add,***

In settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In project's urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from my_app import settings

urlpatterns = [.....]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Then you can add image dynamically!!**

In Templets:

```
<img ... src="{{key.image.url}}" ... >
```